# Python code run on remote server failing with OSError when saving to file, despite saving to the same location successfully earlier in code

Tags: python, keras, server, oserror

I am training a keras model on a remote server (running RedHat 8.4) which I connect to via ssh, after each epoch the model weights are saved to disk. This works fine for many epochs, however after a time it will fail with the error like

```
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'model_weights.h5', errno = 127, error message = 'Key has expired', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)
```

when I use `model.save_weights`. There is no consistency to when this happens, sometimes it will take place after 100 epochs, sometimes after 300. I am running this inside a screen session on the server so it is not the ssh connection expiring, and if I try and rerun the code immediately after getting the error it will be able to save to disk again just fine, at least until the error occurs again after a while.

My thoughts were that it could be some kind of scheduler on the server which automatically stops processes after a certain length of time, but I asked the people who manage it who said there was nothing in place they were aware of which would cause it. I also thought that maybe I was writing to the same file too much, so I tried making it so that the weights are written to a different file for each epoch but the error still persists. I've looked online to research this error but can't find any examples of someone having a similar error or anything suggesting what it actually means.

It should be noted that the server is relatively new and hasn't been used that much so I guess there could still be some quirks with the setup that haven't been sorted out. Is anyone familiar with this error and have an idea of what might be causing it, or have any suggestions of how I could try and diagnose the issue? Thank you!